# How to write PostreSQL source in virtual layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

In QGIS 2.14, I am trying to create a connection with my PostreSQL database using "Virtual Layer". But in the "Virtual Layer" window, how should I write the parameters in source field ?

Comment: First, add the PostGIS layer in your project. Then, you should write your query as a normal SELECT statement (e.g. SELECT * FROM your_table). See: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/virtual_layers.html#id1

Comment: You are right. But when you use OGR provider for example, you don't need to load the file (csv) in the project, Can't we do the same with Postgres provider ?

Comment: ok I got it :"dbname='blabla' host=10.3.1.51 port=5432 user='PostGIS' password='xxxx sslmode=disable key='id' table="terrain"."tbl_blabla" sql="

Comment: Nice. Do you use the ogr provider or the postgres one?

Comment: I am using the postgres one.

Answer (score 1):

You can import your PostGIS layer by clicking `Import`.

[image]